# PHP: Removing white space from an unserialized entry of an array

Tags: php, php-5.5, php-5.6

I'm attempting to concatenate two values from a serialized array. I have this working well. The problem is one of the values `Size` in this case, contains white-space. I need to remove this whitespace. I have used `preg_match` before to remove the white-space from a variable/string. The problem I have here is how I might implement `preg_match` in this instance, if it is the correct approach.

```
foreach($contents as $item)
{
    $save = array();                
    $item = unserialize($item);
    **$item['sku'] = $item['sku'] . '' . $item['options']['Size'];** 
    //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($item['sku']);
    //exit();
    $save['contents']    = serialize($item);
    $save['product_id'] = $item['id'];
    $save['quantity']    = $item['quantity'];
    $save['order_id']    = $id;
    $this->db->insert('order_items', $save);
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: it's just a variable. if you could use regexes before, why can't you now? just because it's a part of an array doesn't change how you use the regexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use str_replace like this:

```
$item['sku'] .=  ' ' . str_replace(' ', '', $item['options']['Size']);
```

Answer (score 4):

PHP has function named [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) that allows trimming strings.

Comment: Useless if the whitespace is not at either end of the string. (`foo     bar`)

Comment: @HPierce Sure, I did not think about that case. I guess we’d need to ask for the actual data that is not working properly then... :) In case it’s only in either (or both) ends of the string, `trim()` should be better/faster.